# What happens when you have Android XML properties that are not supported on older APIs?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile

Will the property just not be expressed or could there be a crash? What is the best way to support older APIs with maybe separate layouts/themes?

Comment: You can use specific layouts for specific APIs. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803620/how-can-i-use-the-new-xml-attributes-and-be-compatible-with-older-android-versio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties it doesn't understand are ignored.  You can generally use them without a crash, although they won't have any effect and that could possibly cause other problems.  You can provide version specific layouts if needed.